# Oracle QSL Developer -> connected to subversion -> show "quick diff" in Worksheet

Tags: oracle, svn, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I use `Oracle SQL developer` to develop PSQL `.sql` files I managed to connect these files with subversion, If I go on the `History` tab:

[image]

I can see the `diff`

[image]

Is there a setting in `SQL Developer` that I can see a quick diff in the `Worksheet` without looking in the `History` tab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

if you're using our subversion extension, use team > subversion > pending changes. Then you can see the differences specifically in the subversion panels w/o having to mess with the history tab in the SQL Worksheet.

or, in the sql worksheet, SPLIT the editor - right-click on the editor tab

[image: see your code and the quick diff at the same time]

Comment: I still wonder that there is no `quick diff ` like in Eclipse IDE ;) 
But thanks for your hints